# Getting exception when uploading more than 100k records. Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Getting following exception when uploading 100k records from a Java web application. For processing its taking more than 2 hours. After the processing of records, trying to get the child entity which is lazily loaded.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "pool-92-thread-1" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
                at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
                at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
                at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
                at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
                at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
                at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
                at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
                at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2150)
                at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567)
                at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
                at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563)
                at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
                at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:277)
                at com.tangoe.matrix.batch.aspects.helper.PrimeJobHelper.updateScheduleRunTimeDetails(PrimeJobHelper.java:111)
                at com.tangoe.matrix.batch.executor.ExecuteScheduledBatchJob.execute(ExecuteScheduledBatchJob.java:135)
                at com.tangoe.matrix.batch.executor.ExecuteScheduledBatchJob.run(ExecuteScheduledBatchJob.java:64)
                at com.tangoe.prime.concurrent.MDCAwareRunnable.run(MDCAwareRunnable.java:50)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:757)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:900)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1078)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3776)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1339)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3818)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1161)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor536.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:176)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1183.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
                at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
                ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
                at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
                at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:140)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIOHeader.readHeaderBuffer(NIOHeader.java:78)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:135)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:97)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:76)
                at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:94)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:530)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:481)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:248)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:608)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:222)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:55)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:743)
                ... 32 more
```

Please let me know if any one has faced the same issue?

Comment: What do you mean with "1 lakhs of record"?

Comment: @Ben 1 lakh means 100,000 in India (and afaik other parts of South-East Asia); I've replaced it with 100k in the question.

Comment: Yes 1 Lakh means 100K records